# How can i redirect to another controller action view using yii call?

Tags: php, yii, http-redirect

How can i redirect to another controller action view using yii ajax call ? here is my ajax function

> ```
> function test(id) 
> {  
>     $.ajax({
>        type: "POST",      
>        data: "id="+id,
>        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action'); ?>",
>        success: function (msg){ }   
>     });  
> }
> ```

From my action i want to call a view in another window.

```
  public function action
  {
     //doing some php code here to create $dataProvider
     $this->render('view',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider),array('target'=>'_blank'));
  }
```

is this possible ? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the answer for my question..

I'm using `CHtml::link` instead of using `ajax`.

**view** :

```
CHtml::link(
        CHtml::encode('id'), 
        array('controller/action','id'=>'id'),
        array('href'=>'/index.php/controller/action',
        'target'=>'_blank')
     )
```

**Controller** :

```
public function action
  {
     //doing some php code here to create $dataProvider  
     $this->render('view',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
  }
```

Comment: You're asking for an AJAX redirect in your question and then you put your own answer, where there isn't even a bit of AJAX. Please, edit either question or answer, so both match, or someone can mark your answer as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do the redirect in Javascript, for example in the success function. You can pass the URL as output from the PHP-action, then pick that up and set window.location.href.

Comment: How can i pass variable through javascript